# Select element with same class and other class

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

Consider this HTML:

```html
Totaal:     <input type="text" class="herd_buy total" name="herd_buy_total" /><br />
Per animal: <input type="text" class="herd_buy peranimal" name="herd_buy_per_animal" /><br />
```

If the user fills in the total, it should calculate the per animal price, and the other way around.

The script should be dynamic, since I have more rows with total/per animal properties.

So I started a function. I figured that I use the class, and if the selected element has the class `total`, I select the `peranimal` class. But I got stuck...

```
$(".herd_weight, .herd_buy").on('keyup', function() {
    var numAnimals = $("[name=herd_num_begin]").val();

    if( $(this).hasClass('total') ) {
        var s = $(this).attr('class');
        $( "."+s+".peranimal" ).not(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
    }
    else if( $(this).hasClass('peranimal') ) {
        var s = $(this).attr('class');
        $( "."+s+".total" ).not(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
    }
});
```

I figured that `$(this).attr('class')` gives me `herd_buy total`, so that makes my selector `.herd_buy total .peranimal`... which obviously is wrong.

How can I select the right element?

Comment: Your name attribute values do not completely match your class attribute values.

Comment: That's a typo... I corrected it.

Comment: Can't 'total' and 'peranimal' be ids? Are they used elsewhere?

Comment: No the can't, there if for example also `herd_weight total` and `herd_weight peranimal`.

Comment: How many animals do you have?

Comment: That depends per herd... That number is given in another field.

Comment: Maybe that? https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/v29jL2qr/1/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to put every row to the separate container (if you didn't do it yet) like this

```
<div>
    Total:     <input type="text" class="herd_buy total" name="herd_buy_total" /><br />
    Per animal: <input type="text" class="herd_buy peranimal" name="herd_buy_per_animal" /><br />
</div>
<div>
    Total:     <input type="text" class="herd_buy total" name="herd_buy_total" /><br />
    Per animal: <input type="text" class="herd_buy peranimal" name="herd_buy_per_animal" /><br />
</div>
```

and in this case you can use the next script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".herd_weight, .herd_buy").on('keyup', function() {
        var numAnimals = $("[name='herd_num_begin']").val();

        if( $(this).is('.total') ) {
            $('.peranimal', $(this).parent()).css({
                'background-color': 'yellow'
            })
        }
        else if( $(this).is('.peranimal') ) {
            $('.total', $(this).parent()).css({
                'background-color': 'yellow'
            })
        }
    });
});
```

JS fiddle example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/fqaqrtxL/1/)